# After Effects - Simple Lighting Effects

Tags: after-effects

I'm currently putting together a simple lyric video like in the link below, but am missing this one piece I can't seem to fix together.

On the left side you'll notice the ball of light moving up and down, adding a nice dynamic effect. How would I go about doing the same? Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

[VIDEO LINK: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z9DKftwgGAI](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z9DKftwgGAI)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a simple animated lens flare. The specific lens flare they use is likely from a package of lens flares you pay for (a plugin) made by Andrew Kramer over at videocopilot, specifically: https://www.videocopilot.net/products/opticalflares/

To create custom light flares without the need to pay for them, I'd recommend watching this video:

You simply create the object, the flare in this case, and animate its' position. Do you know how to do that?